# Resend Confirmation instructions to the user using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I want to resend confirmation instructions to the user if the user has not confirmed his account after sign up. I am using rails 4. I have this code but its not working.

```
def resend_confirmation_instructions
  users = User.where('confirmed_at IS ?', nil)
  users.each do |user|
    if (user.created_at < (Date.today - 8))
      end_date = (user.created_at.to_date)
      start_date = Date.today()
      date_diff = (start_date - end_date).to_i
      if (date_diff == 3) or (date_diff == 6)
       user.send_confirmation_instructions
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am using whenever gem to schedule this task every day.

Comment: Where is the method defined? On a class? How is it invoked? How are you using `whenever`?

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems alright, but you might have a performance problem when you do `users.each` with too many users.

Basically `users` will be an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, that is an object containing a collection of query parameters. Calling `each` on it will convert it to an `Array` as cause the query to be executed. If you have too many objects, that might kill your DB or ruby process.

What about using `find_each`, to see if it makes a difference?

You are also loading a lot of users that you will probably don't need, as you're executing this check inside the loop:

```
user.created_at < (Date.today - 8)
```

That's something else that can affect performance and kill your process. It would be better to add that filter to the active record query.

Try with:

```
def resend_confirmation_instructions
  today = Date.today
  users = User.where(confirmed_at: nil)
              .where('created_at < ?', (today - 8))

  users.find_each(batch_size: 100) do |user|
    end_date = user.created_at.to_date
    date_diff = (today - end_date).to_i

    if date_diff == 3 || date_diff == 6
      user.send_confirmation_instructions
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your suggestion, but is this a right way of resending confirmations instructions to the user using send_confirmation_instructions method given by devise itself ? Because it's not giving me proper results

Comment: See my comment to your question, where I ask for more details. Can't help you more until you give me more info. In general, though, you want to execute this kind of task in the background, and each `user.send_confirmation_instructions` should be further delayed to a new background job.